# System Identification Using Sinusoidal Inputs

Tags: linear-systems

I have a system I would like to model using experimental data. I input several sinusoidal signal and measured the outputs. I can vary the frequency and the amplitude of the input signal:

Input 1: $A \sin(2\pi f_1 t)$ where $A$ and $f_1$ are known.

Output 1: $A_1 \sin(2\pi f_1 t +\phi_1)$ where $A_1$ and $\phi_1$ are measured.

Input 2: $A \sin(2\pi f_2 t)$ where $A$ and $f_2$ are known.

Output 2: $A_2 \sin(2\pi f_2 t +\phi_2)$ where $A_2$ and $\phi_2$ are measured.

Input 3: $B \sin(2\pi f_1 t)$ where $B$ and $f_1$ are known.

Output 3: $B_1 \sin(2\pi f_1 t +\phi_3)$ where $B_1$ and $\phi_3$ are measured.

Input 4: $B \sin(2\pi f_2 t)$ where $B$ and $f_2$ are known.

Output 4: $B_2 \sin(2\pi f_2 t +\phi_4)$ where $B_2$ and $\phi_4$ are measured.

How would I go about calculating the transfer function from the above measurements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you excite an LTI system with a single sine wave $x(t) = A_x\sin(\omega_0 t + \phi_x)$ the output will be a single sine wave at the same frequency, e.g. $y(t) = A_y\sin(\omega_0 t + \phi_y)$. The transfer function at this frequency can than be easily calculated as

$$H(\omega_0) = \frac{A_y}{A_x}\cdot e^{j(\phi_y-\phi_x)} $$

In your case, you are measuring the same frequency twice, which can actually be used as an LTI check. Considering frequency $\omega_1 = 2\pi f_1$ you should see

$$ H(\omega_1) = \frac{A_1}{A}\cdot e^{j\phi_1} = \frac{B_1}{B}\cdot e^{j\phi_3} $$

If the last two expressions are NOT the same (or sufficiently close), then either your system isn't LTI or you have excessive measurement error.

The problem with this method is that you only measure one frequency at a time. Without going into too much detail, the frequency resolution required to accurately capture the transfer function is given by the inverse of the length of the impulse response. Depending on your system you may need a LOT of frequencies. For example to characterize the acoustic transfers function of a normal residential room up to 24 kHz with an SNR of 80dB you need about 20000 frequencies.

Hence most transfer function measurement systems use a broad band excitation.